# Multiple datasources throwing errors with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I m trying to use multiple datasources using Springboot and JPA, but I m having errors when trying to start my server.

The problem only occurs when I try to use my second data source. I m having the following error when trying to start my application :

```
Not an managed type: class com.company.app.backoffice.modelDocument.Category
```

All is working great for the first data source. But it seems that my second entity manager doesn't track the good package. For example, I need my first datasource to manage my model package, and my second to manage modelDocument package :

```
<!-- Configure the data source bean -->
<!-- Website datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<!-- Doc base datasource -->
<bean id="docDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.doc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.doc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.doc.password}"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
<!-- Website Entity manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.app.backoffice.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Doc base Entity manager -->
<bean id="docEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="docDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.app.backoffice.modelDocument"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
<!-- Website transation manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Doc base transaction manager -->
<bean id="docTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="docEntityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Here's the class I need to manage in the second data source, which is in the modelDocument package :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows what's going wrong with this ?

EDIT : Implicit repository to manage entity persistence

```
package com.company.app.backoffice.repository;

import com.company.app.backoffice.modelDocument.Category;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
}
```

EDIT 2 : The controller where the repository is injected :

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Category> categories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your DAO?

Comment: I don't use any DAO. I only use implicit JPA repository to persist my entity

Comment: Shows us theirs injections so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add package scan containing the entities

```
 <jpa:repositories base-package="your.package.enties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have two different datasources and entity managers to work with JPARepository. I think Spring get lost when you work this way. Is is working only with one datasource/em. I have looked for a solution to set in Spring the em/datasource to one specific JPARepository, and I havent found. Despite that, you could follow this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/customizing-spring-data-jpa) to create your own JPARepository implementation and define two classes. Each one to work with different datasource and EntityManager. Doing this, you should achieve what you want.

Comment: In fact, I have two entity managers. The first one is on model, and the second one is on modelDocument.

Comment: Take a look to the new answer

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple datasources, you will have to declare separate transaction manager (`PlatformTransactionManager`) and entity manager (`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`). So Springboot gets confused. To resolve this use `@Primary` annotation. Put this annotation on any one of the transaction manager and  on any one of the entity manager

Cheers